# iniramfs-tools error to TTY1 login but lost keyboard

Tags: updates, keyboard, tty, initramfs

New Member, Very new user of RPI and Ubuntu Mate 10.15

I have 5 R-PI's that we used as wallboards

I log on to them using putty, each time I log in I get a message saying updates:

```
3 packages can be updated.
3 updates are security updates.
```

So I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update`, all the R-pi finish with update error.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So after some googling I find I can run this to fix this error:

```
sudo apt-get remove initramfs-tools-bin && sudo apt-get install 
 initramfs-tools
```

Which is great fixes the error and all the machines update, happy :)

```
until reboot
```

All the machines now have a blank screen asking login to TTY1 but all the machines now have no keyboard so cannot input anything not sure what I would input anyhow

putty still works to all the R-pi's

I have rolled back all the wallboards so now working with updates and have one test box on the test to see if guys/gals can help out.

Thanks

Comment: desktop GUI now back after running sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop but still no mouse or keyboard

Comment: Add this at the end of your question, so everyone would read it.